# Finding log entries of failed user logins in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, logging, fedora

I've been able to find most of what I'm looking for in /var/log/messages, but I can't seem to find any records of failed user logins. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to look for such a record?

I had heard /var/log/lastlog would contain such info, but 'cat /var/log/lastlog' just spits out a bunch of binary that I can't understand. I am new to Linux, but can anyone help me out?

Comment: Solved, i think. If anyone is wondering about this I found some pretty useful info in /var/log/secure

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

Use the lastb command in sudo priv:

```
sudo lastb
```

Answer (score 0):

use this command with sudo privileges

```
lastlog
```

It retrieves /var/log/lastlog values

Comment: OP is asking for failed login attempts, not last login attempts.